# Convert 1D byte image array to 2D byte array in java

Tags: java, arrays, exception, multidimensional-array, indexoutofboundsexception

I have 1D byte array for the buffered image.I want to convert it to the 2D byte array for that i have written the code as below

```
File file = new File("/home/tushar/temp.jpg");
try {
        input_bf = ImageIO.read(file);
        width = input_bf.getWidth();
        height = input_bf.getHeight();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
byte [][] image = new byte[width][height];
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try {
        ImageIO.write(input_bf, "jpg", bos );
        bos.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

byte[] imageInByte = bos.toByteArray();
        try {
            bos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


//here is the main logic to convert 1D to 2D
int x=0;
for(int i=0;i<width;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<height;j++)
    {
        image[i][j] = imageInByte[x];
        x++;
    }
}
```

But i get the exception like

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 26029
    at smoothing.main(smoothing.java:70)
```

The size of 1D array is 26029 which shows the exception.

Now what should i do?

How to convert the 1D to 2D image array?

or can any one know how to convert the image to 2D array?

Comment: That BufferedImage you have already give you access to individual pixels, if that is what you are after. A JPEG is compressed, and you cannot just pull out individual bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `ByteArrayOutputStream` use `DataBufferByte`,it will work.

```
DataBufferByte db = (DataBufferByte)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer();

            byte[] pixelarray = db.getData();
```

and then apply the logic to convert the 1D array to 2D array

This gives the correct image size and avoid exception.